# Iterate through an array on click and change albums via another click

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have a ngFor loop which iterates over an array of famous people (see below), this is fine but I would now like to add in image gallery which is where things get tricky. Each person will have 2 photo albums, the albums will be simply strings of urls to remote photos - the first problem is that I would like to be able to click the image tag (or element close by) and on each click I want the image src to change to the next image, when it reaches the end ideally I would like it to go back again to the start or just stop.

this is tricky enough - but each person will have a secondary photo album which is much the same as the first i.e Array however - it gets activated when the user clicks the `changeAlbum()` which is on a thumbnail image below - the idea is that the first image of the array not in use (as clicking `changeAlbum()` makes it inactive ) populates this thumbnail and the gallery then uses the images from the secondary gallery - so essentially its like a complex `toggle()` between the 2 galleries combined with a click to iterate over the array of each gallery - it might even be cool if when you iterate through the first gallery that it auto switches to the secondary one and vice versa

Im not entirely sure how to approach it though - the html and the json struct are the only solid things I have in place.

```
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let c of item" >
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-image">
                <img (click)="changePhoto()" [src]="{{ output image here from the click }}" />
            </div>
            <div class="card-titles">
                <h1>
                    {{ c.name }}
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-image">
                <img (click)="changeAlbum()" [src]="{{ show image from album not in use here}}" />
            </div>                            
        </div>
    </div>
```

The data structure I have so far is like this

```
    item = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Joe Jimbob",
        album_Main: [{
            selected: true,                
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",                        
        }],
        album_Secondary: [{
            selected: false,
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",
            "https://via.placeholder.com/250",                        
        }]    
    }]
```

This is also relatively solid but im very open to any help anyone can give

```
    changeAlbum(item:any) :void {
      if( item.album_Main.selected ) {
        item.album_Main.selected == false
      } else {
        item.album_Secondary.selected == false      
      }
    }
```

and the change...

```
    changePhoto(photos: Array<string>) :void {
      // not sure how to interate this one by one on click
      console.log( photos.length )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this Stackblitz example I made based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pk6cu8

The important changes are these in app.component.ts

```
  photoIndex = 0;
  personIndex = 0;
  selectedAlbum = this.item[0].album_Main;
  altAlbum = this.item[0].album_Secondary;
  isMainAlbumActive = true;

  changePhoto() {
    if (this.photoIndex < this.selectedAlbum.length - 1) {
      this.photoIndex++;
    } else {
      this.photoIndex = 0;
    }
  }

  changeAlbum() {
    if (this.isMainAlbumActive) {
      this.selectedAlbum = this.item[this.personIndex].album_Secondary;
      this.altAlbum = this.item[this.personIndex].album_Main;
    } else {
      this.selectedAlbum = this.item[this.personIndex].album_Main;
      this.altAlbum = this.item[this.personIndex].album_Secondary;
    }
    this.isMainAlbumActive = !this.isMainAlbumActive;
  }
```